# nodejs automatic url to folder mapping

Tags: node.js

I'm new to nodejs. What I want is to have several apps run at different context roots based on the directory structure. (all must be online at the same time)
For Example:

```
dir1
|____test1.js
|____test2.js

dir2
|____test1.js
|____test2.js

http://localhost:3000/dir1/test1
http://localhost:3000/dir1/test2
http://localhost:3000/dir2/test1
http://localhost:3000/dir2/test2
```

It's desired to automatically discover the scripts and create the end points.
I could not find such a feature in a test framework like mocha.
Can you please guide me with nodejs server url mapping?

**Update:**
I've tried this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

entrypoints = ["/a", "/b", "/c"]

entrypoints.forEach(function(val, index, arr){
  app.get(val, function(req, res){
    x = require("."+val+".js");
    x.handle(req, res);
  });
}

app.listen(3000);
```

where each a.js, b.js, c.js implements the handle but it fails; it does not like putting app.get inside a loop:

```
app.listen(3000);
^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Comment: You probably want a different router for each "app".  Read up about express routers.

Comment: I read about express-autoscan: https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-routescan   I don't see why I still cannot solve the problem. Problem 1: it requires me to specify the routs in the export. Problem2: it does not run continuously for some weird reason. I'm new so I need help with syntax as well.

Comment: Here's [a tutorial](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/learn-to-use-the-new-router-in-expressjs-4) on how you can use the Router in Express 4.x to segregate multiple apps into their own space on the same server.